# Where does GSettings store its files?

Tags: gtk, settings

I would like to have a look at the files the [dconf-editor](https://live.gnome.org/dconf) uses to read/write settings, and I'm assuming that they are managed by gsettings. Where are these files stored on the system, and in what format?

Comment: To find out the location of the files, make some change and run `find ~/.[!.]* -mmin -5`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Following [some advice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8922/where-does-gsettings-store-its-files#comment-11292), I made a change and ran this:

```
find ~/.[!.]* -mmin -5
```

Among the displayed results was `~/.config/dconf/user`. It's a binary file, a sort of database where GSettings stores stuff.

Comment: If you need to read (parts of) that binary file, [this solution|https://askubuntu.com/a/368160/145568] comes in handy...

Comment: Needless to say, this is NOT the unix or linux way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what the manual for dconf had to say:

dconf-editor reads gsettings schemas from $XDG_DATA_DIRS/glib-2.0/schemas to obtain
      descriptions, default values and allowed values for keys.

So to find out where these files are all you have to do is open up a terminal and write this in:

```
> echo $XDG_DATA_DIRS
```

There is where your answer will be (provided it is set) if it isn't set try

```
> set | grep XDG
```

You should find some variation on that name with a dconf folder inside. For me the variation was. `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` which was set to `/run/user/1000` and held a directory called `dconf` with a binary file inside.

Ultimately though, if you want to find any useful human readable information you will be better off looking for the schemas themselves rather than binary files.

Answer (score 1):

A better method would be strace to find out. Using a binary file, why for some wrong idea about performance, how dumb for multiple reasons! KDE does it right but it's not as light as xfce with nautilus!